# Python: getting numbers that are adjacent to a specific number in a list for BFR

Tags: python

Can I get the numbers that are adjacent to a specific number in a list or array? So for the example below:

```
goal_state = [[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,0]]
```

If I am asking what numbers are adjacent to 5, I should get 2,6,4,8. And if I am asking what numbers are adjacent to 0, I should get 6 and 8. Thanks

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: `"Can I get the numbers that are adjacent to a specific number in a list or array?" ` yes you can. But what have you tried?

Comment: What is the input? (A tuple with list indices?) What is the output? (A 1-d list?) Please add some sample cases and what you've tried

Comment: All the lists within the major one are of length 3?

Answer (score 0):

```
goal_state = [[1,2,3],
          [4,5,6],
          [7,8,0]]  

goal=np.array(goal_state)
#i,j are row and column position of the number
def neighbors (i,j):
    neighbors=[]

    if j<goal.shape[1]-1:
        neighbors.append(goal[i,j+1])
    if i>0:
        neighbors.append(goal[i-1,j])
    if j>0:
        neighbors.append(goal[i,j-1])
    if i<goal.shape[0]-1:
        neighbors.append(goal[i+1,j])
    return neighbors
print neighbors(2,0)
```